# When I upload data to R, it changes from numeric to character class

Tags: r, excel, txt

When I have my data set in excel, I have set it to numeric format and all data points are numbers. I then convert it to a txt and upload to R. Somehow when it is then in R, it reads that some data points are character and some are numeric. I am unsure how to make sure that all data points are numeric format when I upload them.

I need them all to be in numeric format as at a later date I use cTree which does not work if the data is characters.

thanks

Comment: try `as.numeric`, then you will see which cell makes problemes since it is transformed to `NA`

Comment: And read the online doc for the function you are using to read your data.  (There are several, and without knowing which one you are using, it's difficult to give you concrete advice.)  The online doc should tell you how to control the data type of imported columns.  Welcome to SO, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

What r function are you using to upload?  if it is `read_csv()`, you can use the `col_types` argument to control how each column is read.

For example

```
dataframe <- read_csv(file.csv,col_types=col(a=col_numeric(),b=col_character())
```